# Pinning a SKBitmap gives "Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data" exception

Tags: c#

I have a `SKBitmap` object and I can access a pointer to its pixels with the `IntPtr pixelsAddress = bitmap.GetPixels()` method. I want to pass the pointer to the pixel location to a native (C++) function. Normally without pinning I would do:

```cs
SKBitmap bitmap = new(4096, 3072);
SomeNativeFunction(bitmap.GetPixels());
```

I'm afraid that the garbage collector will move the object around while my native function is working with its data so I'm trying to pin it. However, I can't figure out how to do this. I've tried:

```cs
SKBitmap bitmap = new(4096, 3072);

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bitmap, GCHandleType.Pinned); // <-- this gives an "Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data" exception.
IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

SomeNativeFunction((*ptr).GetPixels()); // <-- This is not correct
```

This throws an `System.ArgumentException: Object contains non-primitive or non-blittable data` exception. As far as I understand this is because the object contains fields that are not pinned when pinning the object itself. So I actually need to pin the location of the pixels. How to do this?